# Правильное оформление проектов (программ)

Tags: стандарт

Существуют какие-то стандарты на оформление проектов программы? Какие правильно выделять модули? Я делаю: один хэдер, в котором интерфейсы всех классов; реалицация каждого класса в отдельном *.cpp; ну и собственно программная часть - main.cpp. Как все же делается по стандартам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от используемого стандарта, однако **самая распространенная практика** - это отдельный `header` на каждый класс и реализация в файле `.cpp / .cc`, название которого совпадает с `header'ом`.

В том же самом [**Google C++ Style Guide**](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml) эта схема утверждена официально.

В случае небольших структур данных вполне возможно объединение некоторых таких частей в один `header-файл`, однако лично я это не приветствую, *поскольку намного проще искать по файл по имени класса.*

Comment: Впринципе согласен. Если классов действительно много, то в одном хедере искать жутко неудобно. Буду знать. Просто любознательность. Спасибо.